# File cannot be written though partition is not full

Tags: ubuntu, disk-space-utilization, quota

I have a strange problem for which I wasn'table to find any help so far. I am running a website on a Ubuntu 14.10 Root Server. The website uses Smarty (www.smarty.net) for caching. The website is pretty big so after three days the cache directory grows bigger than 50GB which would be normal. The problem can be described as follows:

- After three days uptime the system is down due to the Cache system being unable to write any more cache files
- Disk usage shows NO full partition whatsoever:

  ```
  df -Th
  Filesystem           Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  /dev/mapper/vg0-root ext4       99G  2.7G   91G   3% /
  none                 tmpfs     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
  udev                 devtmpfs   32G  4.0K   32G   1% /dev
  tmpfs                tmpfs     6.3G  860K  6.3G   1% /run
  none                 tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
  none                 tmpfs      32G     0   32G   0% /run/shm
  none                 tmpfs     100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
  /dev/mapper/vg0-tmp  reiserfs   50G   33M   50G   1% /tmp
  /dev/md0             ext3      992M   40M  901M   5% /boot
  /dev/mapper/vg0-home ext4       50G   21G   26G  46% /home
  /dev/mapper/vg0-var  ext4      220G   85G  124G  41% /var
  ```
- The website is stored in /var which is only full 41%
- If I delete any files in /var (I am not deleting Cache files so file permissions are not the problem) the system is up and running again

There must be some quota reached as deleting arbitrary files is solving the problem. My question is if anybody knows about default directory quotas in Ubuntu and how I could determine if there is any quota reached. Of course the final solution would be to remove that quota and allow using the remaining 60% space in that partition.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks 
Martin

Comment: Look at `df -i`

Answer (score 0):

You should check inodes using command df -i as Michael gave above. Your server might be consuming huge inode numbers due to cache.